# Invoice Upload via Ebay Api?

Tags: ebay-api

Is it possible to upload your own invoices as pdf to ebay as a seller, so a buyer can download it from ebay?
If so, how? Which specific api?

I am already doing it with Amazon. But I could not find anything in the ebay api documentation.